# Asp.net Telerik

Tags: asp.net, telerik-scheduler

I am using Telerik radscheduler when I move appointment then I want open a dialog box and after clicking yes or no, I want to go to `OnAppointmentUpdate` event.

```
function onAppointmentMoving(sender, eventArgs) {
    debugger;
    redgrd = sender;

    eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    var appointment = eventArgs.get_appointment();
    var confirmMessage = "Do you want to make this the patient's default Round?";
    radconfirm(confirmMessage,
        function (arg) {
            debugger;
            if (arg) {
                //sender.updateAppointment(sender, eventArgs)
                alert("ok");
            }
            else {
                alert("Cancel");
            }
   })
}
```

I used the code in screen shot,  but after eventArgs.set_cancel(true) I am not able to reach `OnAppointmentUpdate` event.

Answer (score 0):

Calling **eventArgs.set_cancel(true)** means that you will cancel not only the AppointmentMoving event but also the flow. That's why the OnAppointmentUpdate event is not fired. Better try to call eventArgs.set_cancel(true) after you get the result from the confirm window.